# StringVar not keeping it's initial value when created in the body method of a Dialog

Tags: python, tkinter

I have seen behaviour using a `tk.StringVar` with a `DiaLog` that I didn't expect.  My question is why the GUI
behaves this way or what have I done to make it behave this way.  I can fix it by using a class attribute instead of a variable.

In both cases below the `StringVar` is initialsed in the `body` method of the `Dialog`.

In the first example, `class AsExpected` the StringVar is assigned to the class attribute `var` initialised to 'Test'.  On opening the dialog the Entry shows 'Test' as expected.  Anything typed into the Entry is echoed to the Label, linked to the same StringVar.

In the second example, `class Unexpected` the StringVar is assigned to a local variable in the method.  On opening the dialog the Entry is blank, as is the Label linked to the same StringVar.  Anything typed into the Entry still echoes to the Label so the link from the widgets to the StringVar is still maintained but the initialisation text is lost.

From experiments the behaviour is linked to the scope of the variable.  Making it global gives the expected behaviour and including it in any form of closure, apart from `body`, gives the expected behaviour.  I don't understand why the StringVar remains linked to the Entry and Label but gets reset to blank somewhere in the process.

I've also tried using a Toplevel window.  The behaviour is the same as for the Dialogs.  If the StringVar is assigned to a local variable the initial text is lost.  If it's global or part of a closure the initial text is preserved.  Setting the StringVar with set after creation behaves in the same way.

The examples below are contrived to keep them simple.  The simple fix is to use an attribute as the reference for the StringVar but I'm curious as to what is happening to cause this behaviour Tested on Linux, Windows 10 and Mac OS tk/tcl version 8.6.  Or what am I doing to cause this behaviour?

**This behaves as I'd expect.**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class AsExpected( simpledialog.Dialog ):
    """ This exhibits the behaviour I'd expect.  The initialisation text in the StringVar 
        shows in the Entry and Label widgets when the dialog opens. 
    """

    def body( self, parent ):
        ttk.Label( parent, text = "The Entry opens with the initial 'Test' text and anything" ).grid()
        ttk.Label( parent, text = "typed into the Entry still echoes to the Label." ).grid()

        self.var = tk.StringVar( parent, value = 'Test' )  # var is an attribute of AsExpected
        ent = ttk.Entry( parent, textvariable = self.var )
        ent.grid( pady = 5 )
        ttk.Label( parent, textvariable = self.var ).grid( pady = 5 )
        return ent

    def apply( self ):
        """ Sets result to a dict after 'Ok' is clicked. """
        self.result = { 'ans': self.var.get() }

# Create an application to trigger the dialog.
root = tk.Tk()
root.title( 'Test' )

choice = 0
def choose():
    global choice
    choice = AsExpected( root, 'As Expected' )
    print( choice.result )

ttk. Label( root, text = "This version keeps the initial value in the StringVar." ).grid( padx = 10, pady = 10 )
ttk.Button( root, text = 'Click to open dialogue.', command = choose ).grid( pady = 5 )

root.mainloop()
```

**This leaves the Entry and Label blank as the dialog opens.**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class Unexpected( simpledialog.Dialog ):
    """ This exhibits the behaviour I didn't expect.  The initialisation text in the StringVar 
        doesn't show in the Entry and Label widgets when the dialog opens. 
    """

    def body( self, parent ):

        def ontrace( *args ):  
            # Used to test using trace and the button command if the Button or trace code is uncommented.
            print( var, var.get() )

        ttk.Label( parent, text = "The Entry with blank not with the initial 'Test' text." ).grid()
        ttk.Label( parent, text = "but anything typed into the Entry still echoes to the Label." ).grid()

        var = tk.StringVar( self, value = 'Test', name = 'body_var' ) # var is a variable in body.
        ent = ttk.Entry( parent, textvariable = var )
        ent.grid( pady = 5 )
        ttk.Label( parent, textvariable = var ).grid( pady = 5 )
        print( var, var.get() )

        # Uncommenting any of the 3 statements below shows the initial value as the dialogue opens.
        # ttk.Button( parent, text = 'Print StringVar', command = ontrace ).grid()
        # var.trace( 'w', ontrace )
        # self.fetch = lambda: var.get()
        return ent

    def fetch( self ): 
        return 'OK Clicked'

    def apply( self ):
        """ Sets result to a dict after 'Ok' is clicked. """
        self.result = { 'ans': self.fetch() }

root = tk.Tk()
root.title( 'Test' )

choice = 0
def choose():
    global choice
    choice = Unexpected( root, 'Unexpected behaviour' )
    print( choice.result )

ttk. Label( root, text = "This version doesn't keep the initial value in the StringVar." ).grid( padx = 10, pady = 10 )
ttk.Button( root, text = 'Click to open dialogue.', command = choose ).grid( pady = 5 )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your stringvar shouldn’t be a local variable.